# How to request a specific text size in an application for Android?

Tags: java, android, text-size

In my app, I call `textviews` to display text for the user. However, under the settings of a phone under display, text size can be changed (for example: Tiny, small, medium, large). This changes how to text actually appears in my app.

How could I set a specific font and relative text size (like only use "small" text style) for my entire application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dp rather than sp when setting your font size. Sp allows the font to scale with the user's phone text size settings, but dp will remain static.

```
<TextView
    android:text="this is sp text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="this is dp text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>
```

Same sized text
[image: Same size text]

Text size increased to huge
[image: Text size increased to huge]

Answer (score 0):

For the fixed text size paste below code in your dimen.xml file under values folder

```
<dimen name="fixed_text_size">16sp</dimen>
```

and now where ever you are using textview/edittext, set this text size from dimen file like below code

```
android:textSize="@dimen/fixed_text_size"
```